# Circe: force an optional field to `null`

Tags: scala, circe

Is there a way to serialize a single None field to "null" ?

For example:

```
// When None, I'd like to serialize only f2 to `null`
case class Example(f1: Option[Int], f2: Option[Int])
val printer = Printer.noSpaces.copy(dropNullValues = true)

Example(None, None).asJson.pretty(printer) === """{"f2":null}"""
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this pretty straightforwardly by mapping a filter over the output of an encoder (which can be derived, defined with `Encoder.forProductN`, etc.):

```
import io.circe.{ Json, ObjectEncoder }
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveEncoder

case class Example(f1: Option[Int], f2: Option[Int])

val keepSomeNulls: ((String, Json)) => Boolean = {
  case ("f1", v) => !v.isNull
  case (_, _) => true
}

implicit val encodeExample: ObjectEncoder[Example] =
  deriveEncoder[Example].mapJsonObject(_.filter(keepSomeNulls))
```

And then:

```
scala> import io.circe.syntax._
import io.circe.syntax._

scala> Example(Some(1), Some(2)).asJson.noSpaces
res0: String = {"f1":1,"f2":2}

scala> Example(Some(1), None).asJson.noSpaces
res1: String = {"f1":1,"f2":null}

scala> Example(None, Some(2)).asJson.noSpaces
res2: String = {"f2":2}

scala> Example(None, None).asJson.noSpaces
res3: String = {"f2":null}
```

Note that configuring a printer to drop null values will still remove `"f2": null` here. This is part of the reason I think in general it's best to make the preservation of null values solely the responsibility of the printer, but in a case like this, the presence or absence of null-valued fields is clearly semantically meaningful, so you kind of have to mix up the levels.

Comment: I wonder if there is something I can do with Printer to allow nulls only for some classes and not for others.

Comment: Short of writing your own `Json => String` (which is certainly an option), I don't think so.